How to use comlink worker in Next.js 14 app route
I would like to use comlink workers in my next.js 14 project, yet I dont know what is the proper way to do so, I would be grateful to see an example for that
I have read the next.js app route documentation and comlink as well, but nether of them is giving an example for the implementation
